# Good naming candidates for some common name like "info" and "manager"?

Tags: naming

Some books said that we should avoid using names like `'XXInfo'`, `'XXManager'` (I forgot the book name), so I try to find the good candidates for these names, but I can't find some good substitute for `'UserInfo'`, `'ProxyManager'` or something like this.

Could anyone give some good advice about how to select the more expressive names? I'm not a English-speaking man

Comment: Personally, I would use any name which conveys the meaning of the entity it represents. If an object manages a proxy, I'd call it ProxyManager.

Comment: I think ProxyManager and UserInfo are OK as long as they are only used once in the project.  The danger is, that everyone selects these names for their particular area, and that's confusing.

Comment: Plus, I don't think there can be any "Correct" answer to this question. Everyone has their own style. As long as you are consistent it shouldn't really matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of UserInfo, you could just call your class "User", especially if it is in a module called "Data" or "InfoStore" or something like that.   The word "Info" conveys a meaning that can be taken for granted.

It's harder to get rid of the "manager" word - I have tried this myself.  (Sometimes one ends up with so many "Managers" that one almost needs a "ManagerManager" to sort them all out.)
I think the important thing here, is to think "what does the class really do?"

Is it really a Wrapper, Helper, Retriever, Decider, Organiser, or Mapper?

If none of the above, then perhaps the "manager" class is simply too big, and should be split into separate functions that could be named accordingly.
In some cases, you might be able to replace the word "manager" with "boss", especially if it is a manager of other managers objects.

(Answer, because I couldn't fit this long post into the comments)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions like "Wrapper, Helper, Retriever, Decider, Organiser, or Mapper", I think these names are more accurate

Comment: Thanks.  I forgot "Handler" - but it's a bit like "Manager" - you can get a lot of them in the code!